# Does everything need to come to code

Tags: circuit-breaker, electrical-panel

[image]

Okay so I have some issues left from the former owner.

I need some additional items in home and a heating system repaired. The aluminum 60 & 70 amp circuits serve current unit. But I am being told they are not allowed to use aluminum. The circuits run to a disconnect box. So can I switch to copper from there for new heater? There is no ground so do I add direct ground connection to unit through a grounding rod? Or should I just do a subpanel and ground that?

Is the double wire coming out of one breaker unsafe? And what is the green lite ground fault doing connected to the neutral bus? What is this?

If I change this, does this mean a rewire of whole house?

Comment: Can you post a close-up of the jacket/insulation on the existing aluminum wire, clear enough that we can read the printing on it?

Comment: Also, can you get us a *much* clearer shot of the panel, and where on this planet are you for that matter?

Comment: You're asking quite a few questions all in one post, and many of them seem to indicate very little experience with residential electrical work. To answer the question title, keep in mind that code is there to protect *you*. Bypassing it can be fatal. Perhaps not for you, but for the unlucky soul who has to clean up a mess you made by choosing to ignore code.

Comment: What's the nameplate rating on this heating system by the way?

Comment: The gist of the question's fairly clear -- think of the other questions as "side dishes" to the main course re: the Al wire to the heater/furnace.

Comment: One last thing -- *who* is insisting that the aluminum must go? Is this a Code inspector raising hackles over it, or someone from a lender or an insurance agency who's probably in the "well-meaning-but-somewhat-ignorant" category regarding 50+A branch circuits?

Comment: Last but not least, is that panelboard in a *clothes closet*?!

Comment: I agree with threePhaseeel aluminum wire is still legal. I do not use it but unless the wiring is damaged I do not replace it.

Comment: I don't know if Ron will return to answer, but perhaps the new heating equipment is rated for copper only?

Answer (score 3):

### Fat aluminum can stay put

Aluminum was only a problem when thin, solid aluminum wires made from the *wrong alloy* were rushed into branch-circuit service hastily in response to copper shortages.  Fat aluminum wire such as that used for stove and electric-furnace circuits and feeders to subpanels never had such problems, and is quite safe due to the aluminum-alloy screw-lug terminations used with it (vs steel screws and sprung wirenuts).  Furthermore, aluminum wire made since the 70s uses a different alloy that doesn't have the same problems the old, bad stuff did -- this new alloy (AA-8000 series, as it's called) is Code-legal for brand-new work, even.  If some insurance or lending type tries to tell you to rip those fat aluminum wires out "or else", tell them to go read 310.106(B), or ask them what service wires are made from for that matter.

### Your panel is 99% fine...until you consider the location

Your panel, while slightly odd (it's a "split bus" or "rule of six" panel as per 230.71(A)'s "two to six disconnecting means" rule), isn't a Code issue *by itself* save for the double tapped lug, which can be fixed with a pigtail and wirenut as Harper describes (if anyone says you can't do that, tell them to go re-read 312.8).

I can't tell what the weird thing with the LEDs in it is (it *might* be a whole-house surge suppressor) as I'd need a much clearer photo to see the labeling on it.  Don't worry about it for now, though, as you have much bigger fish to fry: either the idiot who installed your panel put it in a *clothes closet*, or some other idiot came by and put a clothes closet around the panel later.  Not only does it look like the location violates the 110.26(A) clear working space requirement of 30" side-to-side even if that space is offset, annoying your electrician to no end, this panel was placed in a spot that's a *blatant fire hazard*.  Overcurrent devices or even panelboards themselves can fail quite spectacularly when pushed beyond their limits, and Code takes this into account in 240.24(D):

> **(D) Not in Vicinity of Easily Ignitible Material.** Overcurrent devices shall not be located in the vicinity of easily
>   ignitible material, such as in clothes closets.

So, either the clothes (and the closet fixtures such as the hanger rod) have to go and stay gone, or the panel has to move, otherwise this installation will get a nice, fat write-up from the electrical inspector no matter what else you do.

Answer (score 1):

### Grandfathering

Your existing panel is allowed to continue in service.  Any new work should be current code compliant, but there's no "mandate" to replace a panel that was legal when it was installed.

I don't like the 2 wires on 1 breaker.  I don't believe Cutler Hammer CH breakers are listed for that.  The answer is simple enough; join both wires to a short pigtail and put the pigtail on the breaker.

I have never seen a ground fault device like that.  The weird subpanel thing that's happening in row 7 is a little weird also.

### Aluminum

The problem with aluminum wire was never the wire; it's the terminations.  And that only applies to small 15-30A branch circuits. In the 1960s-1970s, aluminum wire was hastily used in small-circuit wiring, with receptacles and switches *not properly tested and listed for aluminum*.  It was a problem with aluminum and copper not playing well together.   At 50A or larger, they use real screw-down torque-down lugs and you *should* be in aluminum.

The point is, look at your main lugs.  What are those?  **Aluminum**.   Look at your neutral bar.  What's it made of?  **Aluminum**.  How about those Alumiconn splices, a legal safe way to splice Al and Cu wire?  They are teensy weensy lugs, and they are *literally* **made of aluminum**.

[image]

In fact, aluminum wire on aluminum lugs works better than copper wire on aluminum lugs.    The upshot is, don't worry about that aluminum wire on your feeders.

### Retrofit grounds

They greatly expanded the rules for retrofitting grounds in 2014, and it is now practical to do to every circuit.

Comment: The "weird subpanel thing that's happening in row 7" is what's called a "split bus" or "rule of six" panel -- the breaker in the bottom left of the top half is a feeder disconnect for the breakers in the bottom half.  (Think of it as a main panel operating under 230.71(A)'s "two to six disconnecting means" with a feeder to a subpanel in the same panelboard cabinet.)  These are not permitted new-build by 408.36 Exception 1, but can be found in existing work, and were Code-legal for quite some time.

Comment: Also, while the heater circuits are probably not "feeders" per se as per 422.11(F)(1) and 424.22(D), your logic re: aluminum wire holds just as well for fat branch circuits in the 50+A range.

Comment: One other thing -- either the panel has to move or the clothes and closet have to go, otherwise it'll get written up for 240.24(D) for sure...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the only two things that MUST be brought up to Code are 1) smoke detectors in sleeping areas, and 2) tempered glass when within 18" of the floor or within 18" of a door. Otherwise, everything is "Grandfathered In".  (There are some things that can trigger upgrading, like changing an exit way, changing an Occupancy, like from commercial to residential, etc.  but if you do nothing, then I think it can remain...unless it's dangerous, of course.)

Comment: Thing is -- I doubt that his panel was *ever* Code compliant by dint of its improper location...

Comment: We don't know where this "closet" is in the house, and it's likely that there weren't any clothes there "as-built".   The utilization as a clothes closet may have been a former owner "modification".